# Dynamic imports - Unable to catch error due to compile error

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, import, dynamic-import

I have a module that may or may not use another external validator module. If the validator is not installed in the project I don't want to proceed with the import and catch the error and advice that the validator module doesn't exist.

I managed to handle this successfully using a try catch with require():

```
if (messages) {
      try {
        Validator = require("@test/validator").default;
        console.log(Validator);
      }
      catch (e) {
        if (e.code === "MODULE_NOT_FOUND") {
            console.error("Can't load dvalidator!");
        } else {
          throw e;
        }
      }
}
```

Although this works as expected, I don't feel like this is the way to go and instead I would like to use the popularly suggested feature `import()`.

When I try to use the dynamic import, I get a compile error stating `This dependency was not found:`

I'm trying to use the dynamic import as follows:

```
if (messages) {
      import('@test/validator')
      .then(Validator => {
        console.log(Validator)
      })
      .catch(err => console.error(err));
}
```

I'm not sure if I'm misunderstanding the concept of import(), but I expect the import not to take place if the module doesn't exists and catch the error at my own preference. Instead, it is still trying to import it which why I get the compile error.

Is there any way I can achieve this using dynamic imports or should I stick to my first example using try catch?

Comment: From the message it seems me you are using vue, if it is correct have you tried '@/test/validator' ?

Comment: @dariosicily  I tried this but it doesn't change anything because the name of the module i need to import is '@test/validator'. That's how I would import it in my vue project.